# Automatic IEqualityComparer<T>

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods, hashcode

There are APIs like the `Except` extension that require the `IEqualityComparer<T>` to work. I find it's too much work for such a simple task to implement an interface so I thought why not automate it.

---

I implemented this interface in a reusable fashion so that I can use it with any value and any number of properties.

```
internal class AutoEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public AutoEqualityComparer(IEnumerable<Func<T, object>> selectors)
    {
        Selectors = selectors;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Func<T, object>> Selectors { get; }

    public bool Equals(T left, T right)
    {
        return
            !ReferenceEquals(left, null) &&
            !ReferenceEquals(right, null) &&
            Selectors.All(selector => selector(left).Equals(selector(right)));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return Selectors
                .Select(selector => selector(obj).GetHashCode())
                .Aggregate(17, (hashCode, subHashCode) => hashCode * 31 + subHashCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I then build a new extension which also can accept any number of selectors to compare:

```
internal static class Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> first, 
        IEnumerable<T> second, 
        params Func<T, object>[] compare)
    {
        var mec = new AutoEqualityComparer<T>(compare);
        return first.Except(second, mec);
    }
}
```

Example:

Select all properties of an exception that are not in the *base* exception:

```
var exceptionProperties =
    typeof(ArgumentException)
    .GetProperties()
    .Except(typeof(Exception).GetProperties(), x => x.Name);

// result: ParamName is the only property
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you created a projection and pass that in the class would be easier to use and more readable for anyone coming after you.

Instead of the `IEnumerable<Func<T, object>>` I would change it to be `Func<T, K>` projection and lose the `IEnumerable`.  Which would need to make the class now take two generics

```
public class AutoEqualityComparer<T, K> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, K> _projection;

    public AutoEqualityComparer(Func<T, K> projection)
    {
        _projection = projection;
    }
```

Since we now have the strong type of class in equals we can use the [EqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx) class for both the Equals and `GetHashCode` methods.

```
    public virtual bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (x == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var xData = _projection(x);
        var yData = _projection(y);

        return EqualityComparer<K>.Default.Equals(xData, yData);
    }

    public virtual int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var objData = _projection(obj);

        return EqualityComparer<K>.Default.GetHashCode(objData);
    }
```

I would create a class to create the `AutoEqualityComparer` to make it easier to use

```
public class EqualityProjectionComparer<T>
{
    public static AutoEqualityComparer<T, K> Create<K>(Func<T, K> projection)
    {
        return new AutoEqualityComparer<T, K>(projection);
    }
}
```

Now with the extension method you can create Tuples or anonymous classes for the `IEqualityComparer`

Example could be

```
var comparer = EqualityProjectionComparer<ArgumentException>.Create(arg => new
{
    arg.ParamName,
    arg.Message
});
```

Now to me this is more clear on what we are comparing and anonymous type compare the properties to see if they are equal and not reference.

Comment: This is nice. I was thinking about creating a projection but dropped it because I didn't want to compare each property via reflection. Now that I know there is the `EqualityComparer` I think this is THE solution.

Comment: What a great idea. Worth noting that this only works because anonymous types exhibit structural equality. If you were to project to a type that you'd defined without providing a good `Equals` implementation the comparer wouldn't work.

Comment: @RobH why so negative? Every API can be misused and implementing several equality-comparers for every usage is not less error-prone and productive then a general solution where you only have to think about feeding it with an anonymous type.

Comment: @RobH besides C# gives us this possibility (anonymous types and Equals that works with them) so why shouldn't we use it?

Comment: @t3chb0t - sorry, I didn't mean to be negative. Like I said, I think it's a great idea. I just wanted to make a note that it works through a property of anonymous types.

Comment: @RobH ok ;-) I thought it was ironic. Well, with some APIs (most of them?) you have to be careful and know what you're doing.

Comment: @RobH your comment made me think... I guess the least I can do to prevent mistakes is to check whether the projection is the object itself `x => x`.

Comment: @t3chb0t We actually use this class in our code.  We call it a different name than AutoEqualityComparer and return IEqualityComparer<T>
 out of the static method.  But we do put comments on the method so people know what they are getting via intellisense.  "The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of types.  To compare a custom data type, you need to implement IEquatable interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type."

Answer (score 2):

A quick comment to start you off.

Your `Equals` implementation isn't quite right. Consider:

```
var first = new string[] {null};
var emptyEnumerable = first.Except(first, s => s.Length);
```

Is `emptyEnumerable` really empty? No, it's not. It contains 1 element `null`.

I think this is a dangerous thing to attempt, not least because comparers tend to be called in tight loops, which means you want them to be simple and fast - this doesn't look like it will be.

Comment: mhmm, I see I need to figure the equality check out because with a _normal_ implementation I also get one element. I think this is fast enough. No one will notice if it works one tenth of a millisecond longer and if it needs to be fast then I'll use a `HashSet`... with my comparer ;-D I'll test it with a _few_ integers and strings...

Comment: I've found why the result is invalid when I use your example. I forgot to check if both values are `null` at the same time.